# n read the data from the text file and output each name and number pair on a new line (Python)

Tags: python, text-files

I had stuck with this task and really need some help.

I have a data in the text file:

```
John 46.5 Sam 62 Steve 45.5 Nigel 67.1 Karen 55
Henry 55 Alex 42 Graham 82 Hannah 56 Nicola 66
Ruth 81 Carl 90 Ben 66.8
```

And need to Write a program that can read the data from the text file and output each nameand number pair on a new line like this:

```
>>>
John : 46.5
Sam : 62
Steve : 45.5
Nigel : 67.1
Karen : 55
Henry : 55
Alex : 42
Graham : 82
Hannah : 56
Nicola : 66
Ruth : 81
Carl : 90
Ben : 66.8
AVERAGE: 62.684615384615384
>>>
```

I can output the text from the file and separate the elements it contains, but I can't set up the correct output as it is specified in the condition.

```
f = open("grades.txt", "r")
d = f.read()
f.close()
print(d)
print()

d = d.splitlines()
print(d)
for line in d:
    print(line)
    line = line.split()
    print (line)
    
print()
```

If you can give me some advice and help me solve this task, I will be very grateful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We can open the file and read its contents via a combination of a [`with` statement](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) and [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Note that we don't need the `"r"` argument to it, because it defaults to `"r"` if no argument is passed.
2. We can then split the read contents of the file using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which defaults to splitting on all whitespace when no arguments are provided.
3. We then initialise a cumulative sum to zero before you iterate through the list.
4. We then iterate through the list you created previously with step size 2, so `i` is always even. This means that `split_text[i]` is always a name, and `split_text[i+1]` is always a number.
5. Within your loop, we can unpack these into two variables by using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).
6. Still within your loop, we output the name and the value using [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and an [fstring](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/).
7. Finally within your loop, we increment the cumulative sum. However, since we can't increment numeric values by strings, we must first convert it to a numeric value. Since some of the values given above are [floats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), we must use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) instead of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), because if we used the latter it would raise a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError).
8. Once we leave your loop, we calculate the number of values, which is half the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of the split contents of the file.
9. Finally, we calculate your average by dividing the sum by the number of values and printing that.

```
    # Open the file and read the contents
    with open("grades.txt") as file:
        # split the contents on whitespace
        split_text = file.read().split()

    # Initialise the cumulative sum to zero
    cumulative_sum = 0

    # Iterate through the list with step size 2
    for i in range(0, len(split_text), 2):
        # Use slicing and multiple assignment to get the name and the value
        name, value = split_text[i:i+2]

        # Output the name and the value
        print(f'{name} : {value}')

        # Increase the cumulative sum
        cumulative_sum += float(value)

    # Output the final average
    n = len(split_text)/2
    print('AVERAGE:', cumulative_sum/n)
```

Output:

```
John : 46.5
Sam : 62
Steve : 45.5
Nigel : 67.1
Karen : 55
Henry : 55
Alex : 42
Graham : 82
Hannah : 56
Nicola : 66
Ruth : 81
Carl : 90
Ben : 66.8
AVERAGE: 62.684615384615384
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Solution:**

You can read the text as lines and then split it into an array of words. Try this:

```py
values = []
with open('grades.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for i in lines:
    data = i.strip().split(' ')
    counter = 0
    for j in data:
      if counter % 2 == 0:
        string = ''
        string += j + ' : '
      else:
        values.append(float(j))
        string += j
        print(string)
      counter += 1
  print('AVERAGE:',sum(values)/len(values))
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. It incorrectly calculates the average as 62.638461538461534 when it is 62.684615384615384, as shown in my answer and in the desired output OP posted.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I've updated the code above.